# Remote service start activity from different application (apk)

Tags: android, apk

I have my remote service which tries to run an activity from a different application this way:

```
Intent i = new Intent("ValidateActivity.intent.action.Launch");

i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

startActivity(i);
```

Now also in the remote service app I've added in the manifest these lines:

```
          <service android:name=".UdpListenerService">
             <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="com.something.IUdpListenerService" />
               <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
             </intent-filter>
          </service>
```

Now in the target activity's manifest(ValidateActivity) I've added these lines:

```
         <activity android:name="com.something.ValidateActivity" >
            <intent-filter>        
             <action android:name="ValidateActivity.intent.action.Launch"/>
              <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>  
            </intent-filter>
          </activity>
```

I should mention that the target activity is in a different apk, and it has two packages:

1. com.something (there I have my ValidateActivity)
2. com.test (there I have another activity, which is not relevant for this question).

Now after I try to run it, I still get the error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.external/com.something.ValidateActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the new activity, not in firing the intent.